# Xcode 5 Error will never go away

Tags: ios

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
  count++;

  scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i", count];
}
```

Following off a beginners ios tutorial. He uses xcode and doesn't recieve this error. I receive the error just after (IBAction)buttonPressed saying i need to put in a ; but it doesn't have a ; and when I do put a ; in it doesn't do anything! Please help!!

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question. Also, how and where is `count` declared?

Comment: The error message is "Expected ';' after method prototype."
And count is declared up above. Count is declared as
NSInteger count;

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the method is declared in the interface, not the implementation.

Here is what you want:

In the .h file

```
@interface YourClassNameHere : SuperClassNameHere {
    int count;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@end
```

In the .m file

```
@implementation YourClassNameHere
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    count++;
    self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score\n%i", count];
}
@end
```

The `IBOutlet` property `scoreLabel` needs to be connected to the `UILabel`.

Comment: Its in ViewController.h There is no implementation

Comment: Methods have to be in the `@implementation` not in the `@interface`, that is the problem. The implementation should be in a .m file.

Comment: Found out I have to start everything all over again. Thanks misleading tutorials...

Comment: While tutorials are nice it is best to start with a good foundation knowledge of the "C" and Objective-C languages. There are books and even Apple supplies good documentation on Objective-C.